# How to save drop down list item to database, selected from another table and save to another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, dropdown

I have been strugling with this for some time now, I have a registration page with 3 tables (faculty(with dropdown list items(Id,Name)), staff and students)
both students and staff tables have text fields(name,surname,contactnr, email_adress etc) 
and a dropdown list to select which Faculty the staff/student is under. 
i used a database table to put in my dropdown list items for selecting when the program loads. 
when i run my program the dropdown items are showing perfectly but now i want to save the selected dropdown item to my staff table or students table depending which user is registering.

I did this code below, but its giving me an error on registration that says that

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code,There is no
>   ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key
>   'Faculty'."

and it undelines my dropdown code. anyone who can suggest how to solve this please. Thank you in advance

Controller

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        ViewBag.Faculty = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(StudentsModel U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new     DataClasses1DataContext())
                {

                    {


                        User newone = new User();

                        newone.EmailID = U.EmailID;
                        newone.Name = U.Name;
                        newone.Surname = U.Surname;
                        newone.Contact_Nr = U.Contact_Nr;
                        newone.Department = U.Department;
                        newone.Access_Num = U.Access_Num;
                        newone.Faculty = U.Name;

                        var count = db.Users.Count(a => a.EmailID ==         U.EmailID);
                        if (count == 0)
                        {
                            db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(newone);
                            db.SubmitChanges();
                            ViewData["Message"] = "Successful Registration";
                            ModelState.Clear();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // something to do if user exist...
                            ViewData["Message"] = "User Exists, Register with a new Email Address";
                            ModelState.Clear();
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message;
            }

        }

        return View(U);
    }
   }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Faculty", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: In you POST method you return the view, but have not re-populated the value of `ViewBag.Faculty` as you did in the GET method (its `null`, hence the exception)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Am not that experienced in MVC can you suggest a way to do it maybe a code snippet. Thank you for your reply

Comment: In your POST method, before the `return View(U);` line, add `ViewBag.Faculty = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "Id", "Name");` (just as you did in the GET method). But I would strongly recommend that your change the name of the `ViewBag` property to say `ViewBag.FacultyList` and use the strongly typed HtmlHelper - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Faculty, (SelectList)ViewBag.FacultyList, new { @class="form-control" })` or better, use a view model with a property `public SelectList FacultyList { get; set; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did as suggested and it still givin me an error "The ViewData item that has the key 'Department' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>"

Comment: Your question related to property `Faculty`. Now your referring to `Department`. Are you also generating a dropdownlist for that property as well? In which case you need to do the same thing - populate a `SelectList` (say `ViewBag.DepartmentList`) in the GET (and POST method if you return the view)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ohh I forgot sumthn wif my code so I fixed it, its now saying "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I'm doing for also department.

Comment: Then your model does not have a parameterless constructor :) - The `DefaultModelBinder` cannot initialize your model if it does not have one